# Why cannot read instance when unit testing?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, class, oop, jestjs

*This app is for practice only.

I am trying to create multiple classes here that make up a chat room.

I create app instance as singleton instance.

App instance basically work as single module where it stores all users and rooms of the chat app.

This is what app instance looks like.

```js
class App {
    constructor() {
        this.users = [];
        this.rooms = [];
    }

    addUser(user) {
        const duplicateUser = this.users.find(
            (appUser) => appUser.userName === user.userName
        );

        if (duplicateUser) {
            throw new Error("User already exists.");
        }

        this.users.push(user);
    }

    createUser(userName) {
        const newUser = new User(userName);
        this.addUser(newUser);
        return newUser;
    }

    getUser(userName) {
        return this.users.find((user) => user === userName);
    }

     ....
}

const app = new App();
// Object.freeze(app); Commented out for testing purpose.
```

```js
class User {
    constructor(userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.joinedRoomName = null;
    }

    createRoom(roomName) {
        const duplicateRoom = app.getRoom(roomName);
        const duplicateUser = app.getUser(this.userName);

        if (duplicateRoom) {
            throw new Error("The room already exists.");
        }

        if (duplicateUser) {
            throw new Error("The user is already in another room");
        }

        const host = new Host(this.userName);
        const room = new Room(roomName, host);
        app.addRoom(room);
        return room;
    }

    ...other methods
```

I added a new user instance by using createUser above in the App.

When user creates an instance called room, as defined in user method,

it uses app's method(not static, but imported the instance) "getRoom and getUser".

However I get reference error like so:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getRoom' of undefinedJest
```

Below is my jest code.

What is the issue here?

```
beforeEach(() => app.reset());

describe("클래스 인스턴스 생성 테스트", () => {
    it("app 은 App 의 인스턴스여야 합니다.", () => {
        expect(app).toBeInstanceOf(App);
    });

    it("App 에서 새로운 유저를 만들었을 때 앱에 해당 유저가 등록되어야 합니다.", () => {
        const testUser = app.createUser("test");
        expect(testUser.userName).toEqual(app.users[0].userName);
    });
});

describe("방 개설과 방 참여 테스트", () => {
    it("방을 개설했을 때 방은 App 에 추가되어야 합니다.", () => {
        app.createUser("test");
        const testUser = app.users[0];
        const testRoom = testUser.createRoom("testRoom");

        expect(testRoom.roomName).toEqual(app.rooms[0].roomName);
    });
    it("방 개설을 했을 때 그 방의 호스트는 개설한 유저 자신이어야 합니다.", () => {});
    it("방 참여를 한다면 앱의 방에 해당 유저가 추가되어 있어야 합니다.", () => {});
    it("다른 방에 속해있는 유저는 새로운 방을 개설할 수 없습니다.", () => {});
    it("다른 방에 속해있는 유저는 새로운 방에 참여할 수 없습니다.", () => {});
    it("사용자는 대화방을 나갈 수 있어야 합니다.", () => {});
});
```

Comment: Is app a global variable?

Comment: @王仁宏 No. its exported as const.

Comment: did you import it in your User class at top? If you didn't, how does that possible let user access it?

Comment: @王仁宏 I did import everything correctly.

Comment: aw, app is a instance, import that is useless, pass it as parameter `createRoom(app, roomName) ` or check it outside, same problem, user dont know what is app in that function. otherwise, update more detail.

Comment: if you are referring to the scope of "app", I believe the app still has access to it since it's singleton instance. Meaning, instance is created already at the App level and exported from its singleton class. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: in other word, there is no variable named `app` in `user` scope, so `user` can't access it. at least i didn't find it in your post